# In typescript, Can I use one of parameters passed in function as type inside the function

Tags: typescript, type-alias

Trying to write some generic code. Something like:

```
Function mapData(someTypeAlias: string, data: string){
Const mapper:someTypeAlias 
//Somecode
}
```

I tried it didn't work. But anything similar to this?

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html

Answer (score 0):

You'll need to use generic types. Your code will look like this:

```js
function mapData<T>(data: string) {
    const mapper: T // Some code
}
```

If you want to read more about generics, read the [docs](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/generics.html)

Hope that helps :)